# FortiGuard firewall strange behavior/trying to bypass

Tags: networking, firewall

**(Excuse me for the non-technical terms, my Knowledge isn't the Greatest)**

Context:
I'm an engineering student and I stay in the dormitory of my university

Lets just say that the network isn't the greatest.
it has many of the common problem like (IP assigning issues, Outdated SSL Certificates, etc)

They use some sort of FortiGuard firewall thing and its configured horribly

It works great at blocking unwanted web sites but it also blocks a lot of sites that are not "Blocked" by the IT guys (Stack Overflow, GeeksforGeeks, SourceForge, etc)

I've checked with them multiple times and these sites should work.
one of these sites is Steam and actually any gaming service(gaming isn't blocked)

but it just doesn't work (Chrome says "The connection was reset.")

So, here comes the weird part:

The local IP pool was 172.167.200.1-172.167.207.255

of these IPs I found 3 that works with gaming  (.200.167, .200.72, .200.69)

This year though each building got it's own ~500 IPs and I can't find these IPs any more
(for me the Pool is 172.25.16.1-172.25.17.255)

**Questions:**

**Was this a common thing or someone actually opened these IPs? (pretty sure the admins didn't as they are actually too afraid to try and fix anything)**

**if someone did this, How can I redo it on the new Structure ?**

Comment: I would recommend using a VPN. Try a free one first just to see if the firewall is configured to block VPNs.

Comment: I've tried multiple VPNs and none of them worked,
but I use a Vmess Client called V2rayN as my daily vpn and it doesn't work with games